# Zip file cannot be unzipped after uploading via Dropwizard framework

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey, zip, dropwizard

I faced with the issue that after uploading zip file on a server it cannot be unzipped.
I have REST API based on Dropwizard framework with next endpoint example:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/zip")
public class ImportResource {

    @POST
    public Response fileService(@FormDataParam("fileData") InputStream fileDataInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("fileData") FormDataContentDisposition fileDataDetail) {

        File newFile = new File("/Users/alexx/Documents/"+ fileDataDetail.getFileName());

        try {
            final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            ByteStreams.copy(fileDataInputStream, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws IOException {
        int read;
        final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

Also in Application class I provided appropriate classes:

```
....
bootstrap.addBundle(new MultiPartBundle());
....
environment.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

After uploading zip file, it looks like it uploads, but it cannot be unzipped, next message received:

(Error 1 - Operation not permitted).

Text and image files uploads and opens correctly.

Did I skip anything? Should I add additional params or setting somewhere?
Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake.

I found the filter which works with payload before it comes to a resource.

The filter has next code:

```
    payload = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            if (payload != null) {
                RequestPayloadHolder.getRequestPayload().setPayload(payload);
                InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(payload, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                requestContext.setEntityStream(in);
            }
```

So entity with multipart/form-data cannot be transferred to String and otherwise correctly.

Before this request implementation all other request payloads were JSON.

I have to be more careful.